# How do you delete a column in TextEdit?

Tags: textedit

Using TextEdit, I created a table in a RTF document.  Now I want to delete one of the columns in the table, and I see no option anywhere to delete a column.  How do I delete a column in a table in TextEdit?

Comment: If TextEdit formats the table so that each column starts at the same horizontal position you could try holding down the <Option> key to select the rectangular area of the column you want to delete. Then press <delete>.

Comment: @jaume why not make that an answer?

Comment: Let's see if it works for the OP... if that's the case I'll make an answer out of it.

Comment: @jaume I can't seem to get the ⌥-drag to work with tables. The mouse cursor changes correctly, but it selects normally?

Comment: @jaume I held the Option key and selected all the text in the column, then pressed the Delete key.  All the text vanished, but the column was still there with empty cells.

Comment: I see the problem. Unfortunately, RTF support seems to be quite limited in TextEdit, I can only think of deleting the empty cells individually and rearraging them to the desired width. I added an answer with screenshots, take a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RTF table support is quite limited in TextEdit.

If the column you want to get rid of is not the last column in the table (in which case [grgarside's answer above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119682/how-do-you-delete-a-column-in-textedit#119745) is your best option) you can try the procedure below:

1. Let's say you want to delete column "c" below:

   [image]
2. Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> to mark the contents of the column (note that the cursor changes shape to a cross):

   [image]
3. Now you can either:

   - Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete its contents:

     [image]
   - Position the cursor in every empty cell and press the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> key combination (you can also use the <kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> key, but you will have to rearrange columns later):

     [image]

     until you have deleted all of them:

     [image]

   or:

   - Press Merge in Format > Table...:

     [image]
   - Select the contents of the column and delete them by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd>:

     [image]
   - Place the cursor in the empty column and press the <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> key combination (you can also use the <kbd>delete ⌦</kbd> key, but you will have to rearrange columns later) to delete it.

I wish it were more straightforward, but unfortunately it isn't.

Comment: Thanks jaume.  On my MacBook Pro, I had to press fn+delete while doing Step 4.  Then the remaining columns were automatically resized so that the table continued to fit the entire width of the window, so that I didn't have to do Step 5.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fn+delete trick, I've added it to the answer and deleted step 5.

Answer (score 4):

If it's the last column in a table, you can reduce the number of columns in the Table inspector, available from Format → Table…

[image]